# How to play specific song from music library?

Tags: ios, swift, equalizer

If I'm using

```
MusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.iPodMusicPlayer()
```

To get MPMusicPlayerController how skip all songs to get to one called "example song" (this line of code is getting me music player with all songs of iOS device)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the Media Player framework to explore the music library and find the song you want. Then you can put it into a queue and hand that queue to the iPod music player. Note that if playing the song is *all* you want to do, there may be better ways to do that than through the iPod music player; but the procedure for exploring the music library remains the same in any case.

Comment: See my book for more info on how to do that: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch29.html#_exploring_the_music_library